# Added 'READ_PHONE_STATE' permission, still cannot upload apk file in google play

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

I'm in the middle of publishing the react native app in google play and it gave me error saying[image]

So I added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>` in my `AndroidMenifest.xml` and run `./gradlew assembleRelease` to update the `app-release.apk` file but still gives me the same error.

Does anyone know what is going on and how to fix this?

Do I have to create .keystore file and do the whole process again?

Please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: You have to add a url which redirect to your app privacy policy, under which you defines the use of this permission in your application.

Comment: I believe you are talking about the privacy policy in store listing. I checked the `Not submitting a privacy policy URL at this time` box and this could be why?

Comment: Yup am talking about that, but if you ask for certain permission then you must submit your own privacy policy url. This is recently added in google policies.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: Sweet. It works now. Thank you very much!